# Java program while run again pops up error message

Tags: java, arrays, list

When I input Y (trying to run this program again), it does not compile. The first time is good.
But the second try is not working.
I don't know what is going on, please help me through this. 
The program is like reading a seat arrangement file and put them into a 2D array. I am trying to use the function to read the file and display the seat arrangement. But it can only run one time.

```
package Tickets;


import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
    {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("A1.txt")));
    int rows = 0;
    int cols = 0;




    char again;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    do 
    {
        displayMenu();
        switch(input.nextInt())
        {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("\tReserve seat\t\n");

                readFile(sc,rows,cols);

                // Get user input
                int rowNumber = 0;
                char startingSeatNumber = 'Y';



            break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("Exiting the program");
                System.exit(0);
                break;

            default:
                System.err.println("Unrecgnized option");               
        }

        System.out.println("Again?(Y/N)");

         again = input.next().charAt(0);        
    }while (again == 'Y' || again == 'y');


}

public static List<String> readFile(Scanner sc, int rows, int cols) throws Exception 
{
    List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();


    while (sc.hasNext()) 
    {
        stringList.add(sc.nextLine());
    }

    rows = stringList.size();
    cols = 0;

    if (rows > 0 )
    {
        cols = stringList.get(0).length();
    }

 // Display current seating.
    char[][] auditorium = new char[rows][cols];

    char alphabet = 'A';

    for (int i = 1; i <= stringList.get(0).length(); i++) 
    {                                                
        System.out.print(" " + alphabet);
        alphabet++;
    }

    System.out.println();

    for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++)
    {                 
        System.out.print((r+1 ) );
        for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++) 
        {
            auditorium[r][c] = stringList.get(r).charAt(c);
            System.out.print(auditorium[r][c]+ " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    return stringList;
}

public static void displayMenu()
{
    System.out.println("1. Reserve Seats\n2. Exit");
}


}
```

Error message:

[image]

Comment: What do you, it doesn't compile? If you're typing input into it, it must have already compiled.

Comment: @khelwood, the second time does not compile.

Comment: @khelwood. I uploaded a picture of the error.

Comment: @nidayeshilaozi , this is a runtime error, not a compilation error.

Answer (score 1):

ok here is what is going on,

you created `Scanner sc` in you `static void main` method which you then pass to readFile. you read the file and update the `stringList` list object.

1) iteration one proceeds as it should since it is the first pass on the file and Scanner object has not yet opened the buffer. It opens it, reads it and the `stringList` is populated.

2) in iteration two, the same scanner object is passed! but the object has already read the entire buffer! so the following never executes:

```
while (sc.hasNext()) 
    {
        stringList.add(sc.nextLine());
    }
```

and then you run into a runtime exception (out of bounds ) when you try to access the `stringList.get(0).length()` since it is an empty list!

please try to create a local `Scanner sc = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("A1.txt")));` inside the `readFile` method instead of passing the `sc` object.